# Range.offset propety

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to understand a code on VBA, to debug the VBA program of someone. 
So I want to know that is the property and the meaning of Range (Value).offset(x;y).
Here is my code:

```
`Sub initialise()
Dim i As Double, j As Double
For i = 0 To maxnodes - 1
For j = 0 To 1
    **If Range(initial_range).Offset(i, j) <> 0 Then**
       Range(Startrange).Offset(i, j) = Range(initial_range).Offset(i, j)
    Else
       Range(Startrange).Offset(i, j) = Empty
    End If
Next j
Next i

End Sub`
```

Can you help me please? If you need more details, don't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Offset` property is used to move a certain position from a specified location.

It is used like:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Offset(Row, Column)
```

Where positive values move the position down (by the stated amount) for the Row value, and to the right (by the stated amount) for the column value. Negative values move in the opposite way.

Therefore, something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Offset(2, 0)` (Where `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)` represents cell `A1`) Would actually be referring to `cells(3, 1)` or `A3`.

Therefore, in your code using the for loop and the offset property; the code is creating a new matrix using all the values that aren't equal to 0. (also you will need to remove the `**` to get it to run)